# Escape Backslash only if not already escaped

Tags: java, regex

Very simple test:

```
String value = "Test escape single backslash C:\\Dir  [Should not escape \\\\characters here\\\\]";
String result = value.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));
System.out.println(value);
System.out.println(result);
```

I'm getting the output:

```
Test escape single backslash C:\Dir  [Should not escape \\characters here\\]
Test escape single backslash C:\\Dir  [Should not escape \\\\characters here\\\\]
```

Changing the expression to:

```
"(?<![\\\\])"+Pattern.quote("\\")
```

as in

```
String result = value.replaceAll("(?<![\\\\])"+Pattern.quote("\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));
```

Gives me:

```
Test escape single backslash C:\Dir  [Should not escape \\characters here\\]
Test escape single backslash C:\\Dir  [Should not escape \\\characters here\\\]
```

Which is close, but no cigar.

What am I missing?

The expected output:

```
Test escape single backslash C:\\Dir  [Should not escape \\characters here\\]
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can ever not escape a backslash

Comment: I feel like you're asking for how to get injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
String result = value.replaceAll("\\\\{1,2}",  Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));
```

Idea is to let matcher consume two `\` literals and don't change them (replace them with themselves `Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\")`) but if only one `\` literal will be found also replace it with two `\` `\` (same replacement as in first case).

Something like

```
\\\
^^  - replace with `\\`
  ^ - also replace with `\\`
```

Comment: Sometimes that best approach is the one that looks naive enough to work. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use four backslashes in regex to match a single backslash character.

```
String value = "Test escape single backslash C:\\Dir  [Should not escape \\\\characters here\\\\]";
System.out.println(value.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?!\\\\)", "\\\\\\\\"));
```

- `(?<!\\\\)\\\\(?!\\\\)` matches only a single back-slash character.
- `(?<!\\\\)` negative lookbehind asserts that the match won't be preceeded by a backslash characeter.
- `\\\\` Matches a single backslash.
- `(?!\\\\)` negative lookahead asserts that the match won't be followed by a backslash character.

Output:

```
Test escape single backslash C:\\Dir  [Should not escape \\characters here\\]
```

Comment: Would work fine for most cases, I having trouble with odd number of backslashes...